# How can I set remember values only once when it has data in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have values something like that. This is mobile phone data. For the xxxx, yyyy values here - 010-xxxx-yyyy.

```
    val mobileMidValue by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(shippingAddress.mobileData.second.orEmpty()) }
    val mobileLastValue by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(shippingAddress.mobileData.third.orEmpty()) }
```

I get `shippingAddress` from compose parameter. And it's from API response. So, mobileMidValue and mobileLastValue observes API response.

At the same time, they are connected to TextField. So, when I type, it must be displayed.

The first loading is fine. But, whenever I change the address, I must call API to update the address and calculate the delivery fee. At this time, a problem causes. The problem is the other TextFields are also updated. So, Let's say, the initial value from the server is 0000-0000 I typed 123 - 4 and update the address. Then, it display 0000-0000 again and my old values that I typed are gone.

I tried with `Unit` key. For example,

```
val mobileMidValue by rememberSaveable(Unit) { mutableStateOf(shippingAddress.mobileData.second.orEmpty()) }
```

or

```
LaunchEffect(Unit) {
    mobileMidValue = shippingAddress.mobileData.second.orEmpty()
    ...
}
```

However, the actual initial value is empty values. So, They show empty value.

So, what I would like to do is setting the first data when the response correctly received and then display them. After that, I want to disconnect the observation for them or whatever.

Additionally, I am using StateFlow for the data in ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a flag to handle the update of the mobileMidValue and mobileLastValue. This flag will be set to `true` when we need to update the values from the API response and will be reset to `false` after updating the values.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun YourScreen(viewModel: YourViewModel) {
    // Observe the shippingAddress StateFlow from your ViewModel
    val shippingAddress by viewModel.shippingAddress.collectAsState()

    // Create a custom key based on the shippingAddress object
    val customKey = remember { shippingAddress.hashCode() }

    // Remember the mobileMidValue and mobileLastValue based on the custom key
    val mobileMidValue by rememberSaveable(customKey) { mutableStateOf(shippingAddress.mobileData.second.orEmpty()) }
    val mobileLastValue by rememberSaveable(customKey) { mutableStateOf(shippingAddress.mobileData.third.orEmpty()) }

    // Flag to determine whether the values should be updated from the API response
    val shouldUpdateValuesFromApiResponse = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    LaunchedEffect(shippingAddress) {
        if (shouldUpdateValuesFromApiResponse.value) {
            mobileMidValue.value = shippingAddress.mobileData.second.orEmpty()
            mobileLastValue.value = shippingAddress.mobileData.third.orEmpty()
            shouldUpdateValuesFromApiResponse.value = false
        }
    }

    // Your TextField and other UI components

    // When calling the address update API
    onUpdate {
        shouldUpdateValuesFromApiResponse.value = true
        // Call the API to update the address
    }
}
```

The `mobileMidValue` and `mobileLastValue` will only be updated when the flag `shouldUpdateValuesFromApiResponse` is set to `true`. This flag is set to `true` when you call the address update API through `onUpdate` and reset to `false` after updating the values. This should prevent the TextField values from being overwritten by the API response when you make changes to them.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But, in my case, there's `onUpdate.invoke(shippingAddress)` for calling the address update API. And its response is `viewModel.shippingAddress`. In this case, even though you use customKey, its shippingAddress and, LaunchedEffect watches shippingAddress. So, It will overwrite both cases(API response and TextField). And if you changed something in the TextField and you call the update API then, the old value will be gone.

Comment: Updated my response, try again

Comment: Well, it will overwrite whenever API is called because shouldUpdateValuesFromApiResponse becomes true whenever onUpdate is called and the condition in the LaunchedEffect runs when it's true. 

I solved this it with checking the address data and I created one data called 'isInitialized' and I initialized all the remember values to empty string. And then, in the LaunchedEffect, the key is `isInitialized`. So, when it becomes true or false it will be ran. And also, when it's true I initialize all the values with API response data. Then, it will only once initialize with response data.